# JavaScript how to ensure sum of two numbers is not negative

Tags: javascript

I am creating a math game for kids using JavaScript and created a function that will generate two numbers, first number is positive and second is negative so that students will have to sum the given two number, but i want to generate numbers that the sum will not be a negative number.

my current functions

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

function generateRandomSubtractNumber() {
    var base_number = randomIntFromInterval(2, 10)
    var sub_number = -randomIntFromInterval(1, 5);
    console.log(base_number, sub_number)
    return  {
        "base_number" : base_number,
        "sub_number" : sub_number,
        "total" : base_number +  sub_number 
    }
}
```

I tried to put an if statement to check if the object.total will be less than zero but not sure how to re-generate again if the statement is true.

Comment: Note `base_number +  sub_number` is **not** their product. _"not sure how to re-generate again if the statement is true"_ - use a _loop_?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to generate two random positive numbers and make the smaller number negative?

Comment: You could use `base_number` itself to generate the second number.

Comment: Generate the `sub_number` in the interval from 1 to `base_number`.

Comment: use the first random number as upper bound when generating the second number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can pass base_number as param to randomIntFromInterval.

```
 var base_number = randomIntFromInterval(2, 10)
 var sub_number = -randomIntFromInterval(1, base_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function generateRandomSubtractNumber() {
    var base_number = randomIntFromInterval(2, 10)
    var sub_number = randomIntFromInterval(1, 5);
    return   base_number >= sub_number?

    {
        "base_number" : base_number,
        "sub_number" : -sub_number,
        "total" : base_number - sub_number 
    }:
   
   {
        "base_number" : sub_number,
        "sub_number" : -base_number ,
        "total" : sub_number - base_number 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions for this :

- The first one is to do a while loop which regenerate these numbers while the sum is negative
- The second one (better) is to generate the second between 1 and the first number, this way the first one (positive) is always greater than the second one (negative)

Comment: The problem with a loop terminating on certain random values is that you might never get one of those certain values and the loop runs forever.

Comment: If the range are correctly set, it can take a longer time but it should find a solution
but yes it's not optimal, that's why I said that the second solution is better

Comment: _"should find a solution"_ - these are random numbers. You can't guarantee how many attempts you'll need to find a solution, or even that you can get a solution at all.

Comment: The first approach should never be used and the second is covered with code example in the accepted answer